# Jenkins not able to login on other Ports

Tags: jenkins

When running Jenkins on some other port other than default 8080 it is not accepting the username and password. It is showing invalid information. Have tried with both default username and initalAdminPassword and username password created at the time of setup.

Comment: You set up your username and password on port 8080,then you changed the port. At that time you're not able to login. Is my understanding correct ?